# Will not shut down 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

Gets stuck on splash image

sudo shutdown -h now  - Doesn't work
sudo shutdown -r 0    - reboots system

Running 14.04 lts on HP 250 / Intel Core i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4

I've seen this question asked already so sorry for repeating but where can I follow whats going on with this bug?

Tried the shutdowm -p now, heres the log -

COMMAND=/sbin/shutdown -P now
May 27 18:42:37 Ted sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by dee(uid=0)
May 27 18:42:37 Ted sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 27 18:43:51 Ted systemd-logind[739]: New seat seat0.
May 27 18:43:51 Ted systemd-logind[739]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (Power Button)
May 27 18:43:51 Ted systemd-logind[739]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event7 (Video Bus)
May 27 18:43:51 Ted systemd-logind[739]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Power Button)
May 27 18:43:51 Ted systemd-logind[739]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Lid Switch)
May 27 18:43:54 Ted lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
May 27 18:43:54 Ted lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
May 27 18:43:54 Ted lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
May 27 18:43:54 Ted systemd-logind[739]: New session c1 of user lightdm.
May 27 18:43:54 Ted systemd-logind[739]: Linked /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 to /run/user/112/X11-display.
May 27 18:43:57 Ted lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
May 27 18:43:57 Ted lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
May 27 18:43:57 Ted lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "dee"
May 27 18:43:58 Ted dbus[674]: [system] Rejected send message, 7 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.18" (uid=0 pid=1210 comm="/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.5" (uid=0 pid=820 comm="NetworkManager ")
May 27 18:44:02 Ted lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
May 27 18:44:02 Ted lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user dee by (uid=0)
May 27 18:44:02 Ted systemd-logind[739]: New session c2 of user dee.
May 27 18:44:02 Ted systemd-logind[739]: Linked /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 to /run/user/1000/X11-display.
May 27 18:44:06 Ted polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.68 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

This ensures the machine turns itself off after shutting down the system.

Comment: Doesn't work. Three orange dots on the ubuntu logo then gets stuck. the image remains for longer than a few minutes, until I depress the power button on the laptop.   I have a copy of the log but can't paste here, see above...